# How do you pass visual studio debug argument with a whitespace character?

Tags: debugging, visual-c++, visual-studio-2017, visual-studio-debugging

Using the arguments below

> arg 1 arg2 arg3

Where

> arg 1

is single string passed as an argument

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
DummyClass var(argv[1]); // var("arg 1")
}
```

I understand that `argv[0]` is the name of the program, but how do you pass "arg 1" to be recognized as the first single argument `argv[1]`

Comment: `program "arg 1" "arg 2"` or `program arg^ 1 arg^ 2`  should both work.

Comment: You could also get detailed information about parsing C++ Command-Line Arguments from here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/17w5ykft.aspx